# Relationship of Service and Module in Angular (2)

Tags: angular

What is the relationship of a service with a feature module. After my research at high level, to me it feels like module is a way of just keeping components and pipes together (UI) with their dependencies.

I also felt services have can still stay outside and can be injected in any module and they don't come as packaged in any modules as components and pipes do ?

eg Take a feature module BaseModule and a service class BaseService. Can I ship BaseService to another module by having my BaseModule Imported or do I have to inject the base service every time to a new module, I need base service to be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service added in a module has application scope by default. So it is visible everywhere.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-provider-visibility